# How android Activity handle Object on overriding onCreate function?

Tags: android, android-activity, native

I had bug with CountDownTimer run multiple times. 
I have Button call Activity with simple calling Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DashActivity.this, MenuOTPActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Inside Menu OTPActivity onCreate() i run ConntDownTimer

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_otp);
    try{
        //set time step default
        long ts = 180000;
        //create time counter
        CountDownTime bigOTPTimers =  new CountDownTime(ts, 1000);// I create Class extends CountDownTimer calls CountDownTime
        //start time counter
        bigOTPTimers.start();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception: ",e.getMessage().toString());
    }


  }
```

Scenario: I click the button and go to MenuOTPActivity. and I push back button on android. and click botton and go to MenuOTPActivity activity.

Question: Are CountDownTime Object Create twice or only once?
How if i want countDownTime Object only created once and when activity with this countDownTime Object called by other activity just continue the countdowntimer?

Please Kindly give me answer.

Thank you

Solved, I use BackButton overriding method to close the timer.
If there any better solution kindly share here :D

Answer (score 0):

every time you run this statement the object is created

> ```
>     CountDownTime bigOTPTimers =  new CountDownTime(ts, 1000);// I create Class extends CountDownTimer calls CountDownTime
> ```

Comment: If i click back button on android and start activity again android activity circle will call on resume function or just run onCreate?

Comment: both of them you can put a test message @Toasts@  in each function to make sure such as: in on create: create called, and in onresume: resume caaled

Comment: in my code already put Log.d on onFinish() Countdowntimer. and it run twice.

Comment: now my question updated. How to run only 1 countdowntimer every i call this activity?

Comment: first define the variable as global "outside the oncreate function" then in oncreate check your object if it's not initialized yet initialize it otherwise don't do that